# Aggregate group by months and match by given year

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I'm trying to match by a given year (lets say 2008) and from there, group by months in order to find the count for each month in 2008. So far, im able to group by month, but im unable to filter by only a particular year. The `date` column is stored as a datetime object

```
database.coll.aggregate([
        
        # some expression that will only select year e.g. 2018
        {$match : {}},
    
     {$group : {
         _"id" : {$month : $date},   # group by year
         "total" : {$sum : 1}          # count values in each group
     },

    }])
```

Comment: `{$match: {$expr: {$eq: [2008, {$year: "$date"}] } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{$match: {$expr: {$eq: [2008, {$year: "$date"}] } } }`

`$expr` allows you to use any valid aggregation expression within a `$match`